# How to goog.require JQuery from CDN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure, google-closure-library

I am currently [experimenting](https://github.com/highsource/javascript-module-loaders-comparison) with different JavaScript module formats and loader and also wanted to try out [Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/library).

I've got the [basic example](https://rawgit.com/highsource/javascript-module-loaders-comparison/master/GoogleClosure/Simple/index.html) working, but can't figure out how to use `goog.require` for an external library. Let's take [JQuery from CDN](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js), for example.

Right now I'm doing the following. In the HTML page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

And in the script:

```
goog.require("Greets");
goog.provide("Greets.MsgDivMessenger");

Greets.MsgDivMessenger = function() {};
Greets.MsgDivMessenger.prototype.sendMessage = function(message)
{
    $('#msg').text(message);
};
```

This works as the global `$` is included via the `<script .../>` tag in the HTML page itself.

But what I'd like to do is to load JQuery via `goog.require`, *without* the `<script .../>` tag in the HTML page:

```
goog.require("Greets");
goog.require("$");
goog.provide("Greets.MsgDivMessenger");

Greets.MsgDivMessenger = function() {};
Greets.MsgDivMessenger.prototype.sendMessage = function(message)
{
    $('#msg').text(message);
};
```

I have tried adding JQuery CDN URL as dependency:

```
goog.addDependency('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js', ['$'], []);
```

But this did not work, `goog.require` has tried to load `.../closure/goog/https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js` instead.

Yes, I know that I don't need JQuery for `$('msg')`, but the point is to manage modules (including external ones) with Google Closure.

How could I `goog.require` JQuery from CDN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the intended use and there is no support for it. `goog.provide/require` is a dependency management scheme.  A file that declares a "goog.provide", can be required by declaring it with a `goog.require`.  For production use, the dependencies would be preloaded or bundled.

Unless you want to hack Closure, your only option is to host it with your sources.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that. But can't follow the reason why should this not work for external libraries as well - as long as I define what the provide in `deps.js`.

Comment: @lexicore because jQuery does not have a `goog.provide` statement.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth If I'll save JQuery locally an add a manual statement in deps.js this will work, even without goog.provide in JQuery itself. So absense of goog.provide is not a KO reason, from my PoV.

Comment: Because as @John said, the system is designed for local files - not remote.  See https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/base.js#L1282

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about this.  goog.require is primarily for "build time" dependencies.  It isn't unusual to have runtime dependencies that aren't goog.require'd.